# Matplotlib zorder trouble with plot and bar and two Y Axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a some bars and a simple line.

Firstly, my chart have two Y Axis. The bars are being associated with the left Y Axis, and the line with the right Y Axis.

I want the line be behind of all elements (I have some annotations), but it's not working.

Here is my code to draw the line:

```
ax2.plot([initial_distance + i for i in range(0, len(list_x_axis))],
                         params[item],
                         linestyle='-',
                         color=items_colors[item],
                         linewidth=3.0,
                         marker='.',
                         markeredgecolor=items_colors[item],
                         markerfacecolor=items_colors[item],
                         markersize=15.0,
                         zorder=1)
```

And to draw the bars:

```
ax.bar([initial_distance + i + float(current_item)/quantity_of_bars for i in range(0, len(list_x_axis))],
                   params[item],
                   bar_width_value,
                   alpha=0.9,
                   color=items_colors[item],
                   label=[list_names[current_item] for i in range(0, len(list_x_axis))],
                   zorder=2)
```

Here is my image:

[image]

Comment: You will have to switch the zorder of the axes.  This is a limitation of how mpl does it's drawing (all of ax1 gets rendereded before any of ax2).

Comment: See http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Control-twinx-series-zorder-ax2-series-behind-ax1-series-or-place-ax2-on-left-ax1-on-right-td12994.html